# url rewrite to file without extension

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

this is my first question here.

I would like to know if there is a way to use tuckey urlrewrite to filter a request to a specific file without extension. I tried some rules to accomplish this but had no success.

```
<rule>
    <from>^/file$</from>
    <to>/file</to>
</rule>
```

This file contains text in the form of a json. I could make it work if the file had an .jsp extension. But the requirement explicitly asks for the file to be extensionless.

I tried tags **to type="redirect"**, **rule match-type="wild-card"**, using **condition** tag GET. Everything with no success.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So got my answer talking to some friends. Tuckey wasn't recognizing the file without extension because of a rule that setted the .jsp extension always.

The answer was to put the rule first as this:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/apple-app-site-association$</from>
    <to last="true">/apple-app-site-association</to>
    <set type="content-type">application/json</set>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks! We were having issues getting CommandBox to correctly serve a .build file as text, and it wasn't at all clear from the docs how to add a rule to specify MIME type, but I based it off your example and it worked.